# How to find data type of each column from csv file using Java Script?

Tags: javascript, csv

I have tried to find data-type of each column using Java Script, It prints string data-type for  number,string and date.

I need each column data-type whether it is date or string or number or float.

Without CSV it prints correct data-type.

**Working Example without CSV file**

```
var num=15;
var str="xyz";
console.log(typeof num);
console.log(typeof str);

Output
number
string
```

But using csv file it prints string for all columns.

**My CSV file is:**

```
01/01/1991,12,xyz,14.4
01/01/1992,20,abc,20.5
01/02/1980,78,xy,60.8
```

**I am using Papa Parse javascript plug-in for getting each column and then checking data-type.**

How do I get each column's data-type from CSV file? 
Is there any other way to parse CSV to array where we can traverse on particular row or column?

Comment: I suppose it's worth asking how you're parsing your data... I assume it would be split on ',' but are you doing any other processing?

Comment: I am using Papa Parse javascript plug-in for getting each column and then checking data-type.

Answer (score 1):

While you are loading your CSV in your javascript variable, that variable is a string.

You have to extract your csv into a JSON array and you have to cast each variable accordingly.

Code:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sample.csv",
    success: function (data) { loadData(data); }
});

    /*var data = 'date,name,value\n\
        01/01/1991,xyz,14.4\n\
        01/01/1992,abc,20.5\n\
        01/02/1980,xy,60.8';
    loadData(data);*/

  function loadData(data1){
       console.log(data1);
        var dataPoints = data1.split(/\r\n|\n/);
         //console.log(lines);
       var headers = dataPoints[0].split(','); // if you have header
      var lines = [];
      console.log(headers);
        console.log(dataPoints.length);
     for (var i = 1; i < dataPoints.length; i++) {
        //console.log(i);
          var point = dataPoints[i].split(',');
        //console.log(point);
         if (point.length == headers.length) {
        var json= {};
        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
         if(headers[j]=='date'){
         json[headers[j]] = new Date(point[j]);
        }else if(headers[j]=='value'){
           //console.log(point[j]);
         json[headers[j]] = Number(point[j]);
        }else{
         json[headers[j]] = point[j];
        }

    }
    lines.push(json);
    console.log(json);
   }
 }
```

console.log(lines);
}

Sample CSV:

```
date,name,value
01/01/1991,xyz,14.4
01/01/1992,abc,20.5
01/02/1980,xy,60.8
```

Modified Code

Comment: It is not calling loadData function, shows only link of my csv file in console.

Comment: Edit `dataType` to `application/csv` or remove this attribute and look for any errors in the console.

Comment: Actually I am not getting ajax response that's why it does not go on success function. I added error function and run it is calling error function instead of success function.How to solve it?

Comment: In my csv file I do not have first row as you defined in your sample CSV. I need to find out data-type of each column from csv and put a new row at top of csv file and add data-types.

Comment: 1. Go to network section in your browser and find out the error.
2. If you don't have the header names in your file then at least you have to  know the data type of the fields of individual location, otherwise there is no option [except `regular expression`] to find out the data types.

Comment: I removed dataType, now it is working. Can you tell me how to convert csv to 2d array or JSON where  I can traverse on each column or row.

Comment: I have already given you the code `loadData()` to convert a CSV to JSON array where you can traverse the whole array.

Comment: It is giving empty array in console.Why not is converting csv to JSON array.

Comment: Do you have the same CSV like :
`date,name,value
01/01/1991,12,xyz,14.4
01/01/1992,20,abc,20.5
01/02/1980,78,xy,60.8`

Comment: Yeah I have used the same csv as you mentioned Sample CSV.It is showing empty array

Comment: In console last  line of the code showing empty array why? **Output:**  `["date", "name", "value"]
4
[]`